# Google Sheets - Create Searchable FedEx Tracking from Barcode Scan

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-search

We use about 100 Google Sheets to track incoming packages for various companies. When we receive a UPS package, we scan the barcode, assign it to a sheet, and when we search the tracking number in Google Drive we get the resulting sheet. When we receive a FedEx package, we do the same thing, but the information in the barcode is many more digits than just the tracking number. When searching the tracking number, we get no results.
Additionally, using a formula like =RIGHT(A1,12) will display the tracking number in the sheet (if it's FedEx Ground/Home), but the formula results aren't indexed in Google Drive.
Is there a way to make this work without entering the FedEx tracking numbers by hand?

Comment: _and when we search the tracking number in Google Drive we get the resulting sheet_ Would you please describe what information is recorded in the sheet when it is created, and the physical process for searching Google Drive for a UPS tracking number (and presumably this is the same approach that you would prefer for finding a Fedex item).